# Pandas: Calculate total percent difference between two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have two dataframes. I want to figure out the total percent difference
For example:

> DataFrame1
>
> A
>  1
>  2
>  3
>  4
>
> DataFrame2
>  
>  B
>  1
>  3
>  3
>  4

Total percentage the same = 75%

Comment: pandas is index sensitive .. so your mean the value same or the value + index same ?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
df1.eq(df2.values).mean()
```

Output:

```
A    0.75
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

from your example DataFrame1 and 2 are df1, df2 here:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns=['A'])
df2=pd.DataFrame([1,3,3,4], columns=['B'])

print('%.f %%' % (100 * (df1.values == df2.values).sum() / df1.size))
```

it prints 75%

explanation is this:

```
(df1.values == df2.values).sum()
```

is the number of equal values in the vectors. So it's 3 in your example

and

```
df1.size
```

is the length of the vector. So 4, in your example

Answer (score 1):

```
dataframe1 = open("dataframe1.txt")
dataframe2 = open("dataframe2.txt")
data1 = []
data2 = []

counter=0
for i in dataframe1:
    data1.append(i)
for i in dataframe2:
    data2.append(i)
for i in range(len(data1)):
    if data1[i] == data2[i]:
    counter += 1
print("Total percentage the same = ",round((counter/len(data1))*100),"%")
```

You will need to put your data in a txt file as it is named or even chane it if you want. Also you can just type it in in data1 and data2 as you want.

Comment: In pandas the first value of a list like this is generally the column name.  Hence, there are only 4 values to evaulate not 5.  DataFrama1 has column A with four values and DataFrame2 has Column B with four values.  1 of the 4 is different leading to a 75% same percent.

Comment: Oh i see, i misunderstood it. Thanks for the comment :)